# Slashes in text output

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string, html-entities

From a form, I'm asking the user to enter some text.  I will retrieve this text using `$_POST['text']`.

The user enters the string "It's my text!"

```
$newText = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['text']);
```

Now on the very same page after I've inserted `$newText` into the database I want to display
the text to the user and also use it as the value of an input text box using PHP.

```
// I want to make sure the user hasn't added any unsafe html in their string
$newText = htmlentities($newText);
echo "You've entered: " . $newText . "<br />";
echo "<form action=someaction.php method=post>";
echo "<input type=text value=\"" . $newText . "\">";
echo "</form>";
```

The output is:

```
You've entered: It\'s my text!
[It\'s my text!]
```

How do I avoid these slashes, and should I be doing anything else with my data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing the text through `mysql_real_escape_string()` which, as the name suggests, escapes the string, including apostrophes. `mysql_real_escape_string()` is meant *only* for preparing the data for saving to database. You shouldn't use it when displaying data to the user.

So, the solution is simple: remove the line and use `htmlentities()` only. Use `mysql_real_escape_string()` when you're saving the string to database (and only then).

Comment: Sometimes the easiest solution is the one I automatically overlook. Thank you.

Comment: @Nate As far as I got the question, "remove the line" is not precisely correct statement. "Create 2 variables, one for the database and one for the HTML" would be better. However, see my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Only use `mysql_real_escape_string()` on the variable you want to use in the query, because it will add slashes to escape some of the characters in the string. This works great for mysql, but when want to use it on the page it will look weird.

You could make 2 variables, 1 for MySQL and 1 for displaying the raw text.

```
$text = $_POST['text'];
$db_text = mysql_real_escape($text);
```

Also note that you should use `strip_slashes()` on the data you get from the database later, to remove the slashes.

Hope this clear things up a little bit.

Comment: You don't need `strip_slashes()` when retrieving the data because (when used correctly) `mysql_real_escape_string()` escapes the data only for the query. The slashes aren't actually saved into the database.

Comment: That is correct, forgot about that. Bad practise from magic_quotes back in the days :\

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string() shouldn't be used on the [every] variable you want to use in the query, but on the quoted strings only

Answer (score -1):

> Now on the very same page after I've inserted $newText into the database I want to display the text to the user

**That's what you are doing wrong.**
An HTTP standard require a **GET method redirect** after every successful POST request.
So, you have to redirect the user on the same page, where you may read inserted data from the database and show it to the user.

As for the mistake you made - just move escaping somewhere closer to the database operations, to make sure it is used only for the purpose (YET it is used obligatory, without the risk of forgetting it!).
Ideally you have to use some variables to represent the data in the query, and some handler to process them.
So, the query call may look like

```
DB::run("UPDATE table SET text=s:text",$_POST['text']);
```

where `s:text` is such a variable (called placeholder), which will be substituted with the `$_POST['text']` value, properly prepared according to the type set in the placeholder name (`s` means "string", tells your function to escape and quote the data)
So, all the necessary preparations will be done inside and will spoil no source variable.

Answer (score -2):

save normally using mysql_real_escape_string()

and when you want to display it in a form:

```
htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($row['text_data']))
```

it will do the trick.

Comment: So... get dressed, then get naked again? Why not just stay naked?

Comment: you missed the point. lets say you have a text area that can accept HTML. you want to save it as raw as possible to the database. the method i stated shows show you save it to the database and put it on the form again. if you want it printed as is, you only do stripslashes() (without the htmlspecialchars()). this goes for html editors...

Comment: You're missing the point to. m_r_e_s() is for database operations. You don't stuff its output back into an html form. And un-doing the operation via stripslashes is pointless since the ORIGINAL un-escaped version is still available.

Comment: it's a solution for using the raw data back in a form. if he fetches it from the database after saving it from user input (not taking in mind gpc) he will get additional slashes. stripslashes fixes it and when you put it in a form you need to encode the html entities.

Comment: uh, no. the slashes don't get stored in the database.

Comment: Also, in the OPs case the data isn't coming from a database. It's coming directly from the user. Doing `stripslashes( mysql_real_escape_string( $foo ) )` doesn't make any sense.